# Disappearing playbar on Vimeo on iPhone 6s. Possible Z-index issue?

Tags: css, ios, video, z-index, vimeo

I am coding a mobile version of a website, and the test homepage can be seen at http://titanskateboardtools.com/mobilesite/index-hidden.html

If you scroll down you will see the video. You should try and look at this page on an iPhone 6s if possible. I think the simulator in Chrome, for example, DOES display the playbar.

Basically there is no playbar (control) even though it is not set to be hidden, so I had to modify the thumbnail and mock up a play button. If you touch the thumbnail the video does play, but the controls  are not visible. So if you want to pause the video or mute it, the only option is mute your phone. When I touch the video for a split second, I see the video controls. But they disappear and holding my finger down does not keep it visible. I believe it does a quick z-index layer swap or something. Here is the embed code. I'm not a coder in any shape or form so, any fix will have to be very dumbed down. I.e., 'create this file, name it XYZ, paste this into it, stick it in the root' then in the head tag (or whatever) paste this in, changing this part to XYZ'. You get the idea. I can drive a car but don't know how the engine works. My specialty is marketing not coding. I am aware of the concept to assign 2 different z-indexes(ices) but with this div and iframe I have clue where those would go to effect video controls. :)

```
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
<div style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;">
    <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/502246225?controls=true&badge=0&amp;autopause=0&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479" 
        name="iframe" frameborder="0" z-index=100 style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;" 
        title="TITAN Skateboard Tools&amp;reg;" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance. This is my first post here.